# What is the point of adding another value to os.environ.get?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm looking at an example like this:

```
settings = {
    'host': os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_HOST', '[YOUR ENDPOINT]'),
    'master_key': os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_KEY', '[YOUR KEY]'),
    'database_id': os.environ.get('COSMOS_DATABASE', '[YOUR DATABASE]'),
    'container_id': os.environ.get('COSMOS_CONTAINER', '[YOUR CONTAINER]'),
    'tenant_id': os.environ.get('TENANT_ID', '[YOUR TENANT ID]'),
    'client_id': os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID', '[YOUR CLIENT ID]'),
    'client_secret': os.environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET', '[YOUR CLIENT SECRET]'),
}
```

What is the point of adding things like `'[YOUR ENDPOINT]'`? It's not expecting me to put the actual value there right? It should just access my environment variable called `ACCOUNT_HOST` to get the value, otherwise there would be no real reason to use environment variables right?

Are they just being put there to add more clarification as to what the environment variable pertains to?

Comment: It's a default value to be used if the variable *isn't* in the environment.

Comment: @chepner ah okay, interesting. Thank you!

Comment: `os.environ` is a "[mapping object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping)", so it has a [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method like a dictionary. Providing a default value prevents `KeyErrors` from being raised when the key isn't found.